# How to change x axis starting point to '0' in seaborn plot

Tags: python, seaborn

I was plotting a joint plot using seaborn how can I set x axis starting point to '0'.

```
ad_data=pd.read_csv('advertising.csv')
sns.jointplot(y='Area Income',x='Age',data=ad_data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recognize that joinplot has an inbuilt argument "xlim" which can be directly passed into the function arguments.

```
sns.jointplot(y='Area Income',x='Age',data=ad_data,xlim=(0,70))
```

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axkua.png)